# Problems with levels in a xtab in R

Tags: r, data.table

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
                                        4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"), class = "factor"), 
                     result = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
                     weight = c(0.5, 0.8, 1, 3, 3.4, 1.6, 4, 1.6, 2.3, 2.1, 2, 
                                1, 0.1, 6, 2.3, 1.6, 1.4, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 
                                1.6, 1.8)), .Names = c("area", "result", "weight"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                        -26L))
```

I am trying to isolate areas with the highest and lowest regions and then produce a weighted crosstab which is then used to calculate risk difference.

```
 df.summary <- setDT(df)[,.(.N, freq.1 = sum(result==1), result = weighted.mean((result==1), 
                                                                                   w = weight)*100), by = area]

#Include only regions with highest or lowest percentage
df.summary <- data.table(df.summary)
incl <- df.summary[c(which.min(result), which.max(result)),area]
df.new <- df[df$area %in% incl,]
incl
```

'incl' has the two areas that I want, but still the four levels:

```
[1] a2 a3
Levels: a1 a2 a3 a4
```

How do I get rid of the levels as well?  The subsequent analysis that I want to do needs just the two levels as well as the areas.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this elsewhere on the web (e.g. [Problems with levels in a xtab in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649374/problems-with-levels-in-a-xtab-in-r))

```
df.new$area <- factor(df.new$area)
```

It works!

Hope it's useful for others.

Comment: But it's a data.table, so `df.new[,area:=factor(area)]` to save variable name repetition of `df.new` is more idiomatic.